# VBA Automatic Application.Username Not Populating Correctly

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been working on trying to automate some functions on a spreadsheet and for the most part have had the VBA codes that I have written behave as intended. But the one that is making me crazy is the one to auto-populate the application username. So I am running it as a Sub, Because I have a few different functions running, here is the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4:A198")) Is Nothing Then
        Call AutoName
     End If
End Sub
Sub AutoName()
    Dim myCells As Range
    Set myCells = Selection
    If myCells = (myCells.Value) Then
         With myCells(1, 6)
        .Value = Application.UserName
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
        With myCells(1, 5)
        .Value = Date
        End With
    Else
        With myCells(1, 6)
        .Value = Null
        End With
        With myCells
        .Value = Null
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

When I enter information into the first cell it auto inputs the date and username into the correct cells like it is supposed to but then the issue is two fold, the first is when I delete the input in the first cell this happens.

[image: Spreadsheet Pic]
The Username remains in the TM column and then populates in the date column, and then the date populates in the case column! I have tried adding .ClearContents, Range.Delete but it still happens regardless. I am at my wits end with it. It isn't the end of the world, it functions as intended for the most part, its just kind of an annoying thing. Secondary problem which, again, is just annoying, is that if I hit delete when in that first cell it auto-populates the name in the Date cell and the date in the case cell. Again not the end of the world, just annoying. Any help would be appreciated as to where I am going wrong. 
In case it wasn't evident I am new to VBA

Comment: So if you hit delete, the cells in F and G should be cleared as well?

Comment: Side note: the `Application.UserName` is just a user-configurable setting in Excel options. You might want to use `Environ$("USERNAME")` to get the actual Windows login name - environment variables are still spoofable, but much less easily than Excel options, and the USERNAME value would normally match the domain user, assuming you're on a domain.

Comment: Yes the idea was that if you hit delete then the cells in F and G should be cleared as well. Which when I placed the code into a separate sheet it worked worked awesomely! Thank you so much! I felt like I was going insane.... That is interesting about the Windows Username Vs Excel Username. If I may ask, I am looking at your code and trying to see the where I went wrong, was it that it did not know where to look specifically because of the lack of Offset?

Comment: Your `myCells(1, 5)` and `myCells(1, 6)` are off by a column. `5` and `6` don't actually offset 5 and 6 columns.

Comment: One way to check. Let's say `myCells` is `A4`. In the Immediate Window, put `? Range("A4").Cells(1,5).Address` and hit Enter. You get `$E$4`, not `$F$4`.

Comment: Well I feel silly, thank you for taking the time to help and let me know where I went wrong. If i could ask for one further thing, what are some good resources to learn more about VBA?

Comment: That's a cool test to know how to do, thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you might want to rewrite like this, using `Offset` to make clear which columns you're working with,  and also passing a range to `AutoName` instead of relying on `Selection`. Also, if you make changes to multiple cells at once, your current code will fail. Best to loop through each cell in the `Intersect`ion of the specific range and `Target`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A4:A198")) Is Nothing Then
        AutoName rng:=Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A4:A198"))
     End If
End Sub

Sub AutoName(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            With cell.Offset(, 6)
                .Value = Application.UserName
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
            With cell.Offset(, 5)
                .Value = Date
            End With
        Else
            With cell.Offset(, 5).Resize(, 2)
                .ClearContents
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe OP meant to ping you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753940/vba-automatic-application-username-not-populating-correctly#comment103797427_58753940)